# WYSIWYG editor, markdown or bbcode or wiki or what

Tags: php, editor, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I'm finding some editors that say they use bbcode or markdown or wiki, etc.

Can someone explain what this is all about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a simplified set of mark-up language tags to help with formatting of content in situations where you do not trust the data being entered, it will prevent users having to enter direct html that may otherwise break a page or permit exploits from working their way into the page's output. These tags will be processed and formatted into HTML by the software.

Typing this answer into Stackoverflow required me to use a form of markup/markdown language :)

eg

```
[b]Bold[/b]
[url=http://www.google.com]Link Text[/url]
[img]http://www.domain.com/image.jpg[/img]
```

For wikipedia entries on each type of markup:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBCode
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Wiki_markup
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown

Answer (score 0):

[BBCode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBCode), [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) and [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikitext) are markup languages used for writing the code on web pages that support user-entered content.

This is quite often to include one or more of these markups instead of enabling the whole WYSIWYG editor, especially when usually users enter text without any markup or with limited features.

Googling does not hurt.